# Proof that there exists a subsequence is strictly increasing or decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that a sequence of nonzero numbers converging to zero must have a subsequence that is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Comment: ...or you can use the fact that *every* sequence has a monotone subsequence to reduce the problem to a simpler one.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson How is that generalized problem "simpler"? And if you prove your alternative statement (in a simple manner?), how do you get from monotone to strictly monotone?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen A general principle is to reduce (if possible) any problem to a simpler one (assuming that you can appeal to this fact without comment).  So we have $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3 \geq ... \geq a_n \to 0$. For every integer $k$ there is a $ n_k$ so that $a_{n_k}<  a_{n_{k-1}} $  etc.  Sometimes reducing a problem saves a lot of work; here it saves a little work (if you can cite the fact that sequences always have monotone subsequences).

Comment: Also, if you accept that all sequences have monotone subsequences (proved in most modern texts) there is an easy corollary: *A sequence has a strictly monotone subsequence if and only if the range of the sequence is infinite.*  Then this problem can be solved by applying that characterization.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of non-zero numbers that converges to $0$. $(a_n)$ must have a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that is either always positive or always negative, since if not, only finitely many terms in the sequence would be non-zero.

Lets assume the subsequence is always positive, the construction works the same if it's always negative. Construct a further subsequence of $a_{n_k}$ as follows:

Let $a_{n_{k_1}}=a_{n_0}$.

Let $a_{n_{k_j}}$ be a point in the sequence $(a_{n_k})$ that lies in the ball of radius $a_{n_{k_{j-1}}}/2$ around 0 and comes after $a_{n_{k_{j-1}}}$ in the sequence.

Such a point always exists, because the sequence converges to $0$, so there exists a $K$ such that for all $k>K$, $a_{n_k}$ is in the ball of radius $a_{n_{k_{j-1}}}/2$ around 0. This sequence is strictly decreasing, since each point is positive and at most half the value of the previous point. Finally, this sequence is a subsequence of a subsequence of $a_n$, so it is itself a subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be the sequence. For each $\epsilon>0$ all but a finite number of the $a_n$ have $|a_n|<\epsilon$. Either infinitely many $a_n$ are positive or infinitely many are negative or both. Suppose positive.  For each integer $n\ge 1$ let $a_{i_n}>0$ be $<1/n$ and, if $n\ge 2$, $\lt a_{i_n-1}$.  The sequence of $a_{i_n}$ is the desired decreasing subsequence converging to zero.  If infinitely many $a_n$ are not positive, then we carry out the analogous process with signs reversed.